# How to use LISTAGG to concatenate from multiple rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5

I have report query along these lines in APEX 5.0:

```
WITH inner_table AS
( select distinct 
 i.ID
,i.name
,i.lastname
,case i.gender
   when 'm' then 'Male'
   when 'f' then 'Female'
 end gender
,i.username
,b.name region
,i.address
,i.city city
,i.EMAIL
,r.name as "ROLE"
,ie.address as "region_location"
,case 
   when i.gender='m' THEN 'blue'
   when i.gender='f' THEN '#F6358A'
END i_color
,b.course as COURSE
,si.city UNIVERSITY
,case 
when i.id in (select app_user from scholarship) then 'check'
else 'close'
end as scholarship,
case
when i.id in (select ieur.app_user from ie_user_role ieur where role=4) then 'Admin'
else ''
end admin,
apex_item.checkbox(10, i.id, 'UNCHECKED onclick="highlightRow(this);"') as Del_usr
from  app_users i left join regions b on (i.region=b.id)
left join ie_user_role ur on (i.id = ur.app_user)
left join ie_roles r on(ur.role = r.id)
left join user_house uh on (i.id=uh.app_user)
left join reg_location ie on (uh.house=ie.id)
left join study_list sl on i.id = sl.insan
left join study_institute si on sl.institute = si.id
left join course c on sl.course = c.id
where i.is_active='Y'
order by
i.name,i.lastname,i.username,region, city, i.EMAIL) 
 SELECT * FROM inner_table where (scholarship = :P5_SCHOLARSHIP or :P5_SCHOLARSHIP is null)
```

I might get results like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------|------------------|
|        Name         |     Lastname     |  ...  |      Course      |
|---------------------|------------------|-------|------------------|
|        Some         |       User       |  ...  | Course1          |
|---------------------|------------------|-------|------------------|
|        Some         |       User       |  ...  | Course2          |
|---------------------|------------------|-------|------------------|
```

But I would like to achieve enlisted courses in same row, that was repeating previously, so:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------|------------------|
|        Name         |     Lastname     |  ...  |      Course      |
|---------------------|------------------|-------|------------------|
|        Some         |       User       |  ...  | Course1, Course2 |
|---------------------|------------------|-------|------------------|
```

I tried using LISTAGG, and I didn't note down my attempts, so unfortunately I can't post that now. I basically tried:

```
,LISTAGG(b.course, ', ') within group (order by b.course) as COURSE
```

Then adding GROUP BY using COURSE, but in that case whole query is affected by GROUP BY and I have to apply other columns correctly, right? Otherwise its resulting in "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function". I got lost a bit there.

Other thing I tried is using a subquery table with same LISTAGG line above, and got wanted output from subquery, but then joining to the rest of the query didn't provide expected results.

I think I could use a bit of SQL help here for LISTAGG when joining multiple tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an aggregate function (that collapses multiple rows into one) you need a `GROUP BY` clause, so you'd need something like this:

```
SELECT i.username, 
       LISTAGG( c.course, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY ( c.course )
  FROM app_users i
   ...
  LEFT JOIN course c on sl.course = c.id
 GROUP BY i.username
```

Basically, anything that's not being aggregated, needs to be in the `GROUP BY` clause. Try it in a much simpler query until you get the hang of it, then make your big one.

Comment: Hi,
This solves the issues I was having with not using GROUP BY properly here, yes. In case of the whole query though, I'm not getting correct results. In original query there were 694 records, and using LISTAGG its 691. When checking if there's 3 records less because they were repeating on Course under same user(s), as expected, I find that same course is shown twice for 4 users as listagg, ie. 'Course1, Course1') - which is "false" result. While for other 2 its showing correctly, different courses for same user listed in one row with ', '.  Its kind of difficult to verify this now.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but now I see I might have some mistakes in original query, not related to listagg, but that's a different issue...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is LISTAGG with an analytical window function. Then remove duplicates using distinct. Here is my sample result/ data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e8e3f/3

Select DISTINCT name, last_name, other columns,
LISTAGG(course, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY course)
         OVER (PARTITION BY name, last_name) as "Course"
  FROM inner_table;

Comment: Thanks. 
Both your solution and the one from previous reply work correctly related to my original question.
In both cases, I get 4 users with course repeating in LISTAGG column twice, like 'Course1, Course1', and this 100% points to faulty SQL in original query, I will investigate accordingly.

Comment: upvoted now, earlier it reported that I can upvote but its not publicly  displayed until certain reputation points.

Comment: Additional question... How can I remove duplicates from LISTAGG? For example, user will have 2 different "roles", so those are two rows for same user. I can (and should) put ROLE column under listagg too, but it will still show like: "someuser", "role1, role2", "course123, course123", and vice versa - "someuser", "role5, role5", "course2, course3".